# HTML - Header (html,css)

Tags: javascript, html, css, header

So we need to make a header from a soccer site for a school project, so i got https://www.granadacf.es/en. So my question is how do i make the text and the header like it is on the image. My image doesn't stay in the middle when resizing the website and the text isnt centered, like theres too much space. [image]
This is my code so far.

```css
#header{
    background-color: #a61b2b;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    min-height: 120px;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: flex-end
}

#topnav{
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',arial,sans-serif;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #eb0627;
}

#topnav a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff
}

#topnav li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#topnav li ul li{
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

#logo{
    position: relative;
    left: 500px;
    width: 55%;
}

.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Granada Club de Fútbol | Granada </title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <img alt="Logo" id="logo" src="images/logo.png">
    <ul id="topnav">
        <li><a href="#">NEWS</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">CLUB</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">FIRST TEAM</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">THE CLUB</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">CLUB INFORMATION</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">STRUCTURE</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">FIRST TEAM</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">SQUAD </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TRAINING</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">TEAMS</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">GRANADA B </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GFC LADIES</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">GRANADA TV</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```